# Pause script till website fully loaded - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm currently trying to create a sheet which will extract tracking information for parcels sent out. I've worked out the following code for the time being but encounter the following issues:

1. The code continues before the page fully loads, I suspect this may be because after the initial loading is complete, it runs a script and refreshes.
2. If mouse is not rolling over Internet Explorer, high probability of a human verification with images. I understand this may not be possible to avoid but is there any way I can pause the script while someone completes the verification?

   ```
   Sub RoyalTrack()

       Dim i As Long
       Dim ie As Object
       Dim t As String

       Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       With ie
           .Visible = True
           .Navigate "https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/SF511991733GB"
           .Resizable = True
       End With

       While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

       Dim full As Variant
       Dim latest As Variant

       full = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("c-tracking-history")(0).innerText
       latest = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("tracking-history-item ng-scope")(0).innerText

       MsgBox full
       MsgBox latest

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: please rephrase point 2 - I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: I guess automating Web applications is not feasible with excel vba due to this loading issue. I have tried it too but no luck.

Comment: Firstly, I agree with @dv3, I don't understand what you are trying to say in second point. Please rephrase your point. I suspect what you are trying to say is can the UDF wait until a human performs some action on the site? If so, after an action is performed, I presume that you land on a different page or something changes in current page? If so, wait for that particular field/property to appear. But as you can see that there are a lot of questions that need answering before we can come up with a solution

Comment: To rephrase the second point, once IE is opened and web page is loading, if I do not actively click or move my mouse over the browser, a pop up comes up for Google bot verification. Essentially an image check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Added a 2 second wait after page loads to allow loading and an error handler to identify if the required property is available.

```
Sub RoyalTrack()


Dim i As Long
Dim ie As Object
Dim t As String
Dim trackingN As String
Dim count As Integer
count = 2

Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & count).Value <> ""

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
trackingN = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & count).Value
    With ie
    .Visible = True
  ' Variable tracking SF-GB
    .Navigate "https://www.royalmail.com/track-your-item#/tracking-results/" & trackingN
    .resizable = True
End With

While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

Dim full As Variant
Dim latest As Variant

On Error Resume Next
latest = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tracking-history-item ng-scope")(0).innerText

If Err Then
    MsgBox "Prove your humanity if you can"
    Err.Clear
End If

latest = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tracking-history-item ng-scope")(0).innerText

Windows("Book1.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Range("E" & count).Value = latest

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
count = count + 1

Loop

End Sub
```